# Empirical distribution. Problem with changing variables

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, probability-theory

We have iid random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ with continuous cdf $F$. Define empirical distribution function $\hat{F}_n (x)= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{I}_{\{X_i \le x \}}$. Let's consider $\int h(\hat{F}_n(x), F(x))\hat{F}_n (\mbox{d}x)$ . I would like to substitute $F(x)=:y$, but I don't knon how to deal with $\hat{F}_n (\mbox{d}x)$. If $F$ was strictly increasing ($ F^{-1}$ exists) and distribution of $X_i$ had density it would be easy. What if we don't have such strong assumptions?

Comment: What meaning to you give to $\int u(x)v(\mathrm dx)$ when $v$ is a *function*? Did you intend to write $\int u(x)\mathrm d v(x)$?

Comment: Yes. I thought that those notations are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the definition, note that the continuity of the distribution implies there are no tie in the sample, hence
$$
\int_\mathbb R h(\hat{F}_n(x), F(x))\mbox{d}\hat{F}_n(x)=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nh(\hat{F}_n(X_k), F(X_k))=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nh\left(\frac{k}n, F(X_{k:n})\right),
$$
where $(X_{k:n})_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ is the ordered sample $(X_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$.
Unfortunately, I might not be getting your idea of "substitution" in this context.